# My cpanel & whm not showing the login form

Tags: cpanel, whm

My cpanel and whm not showing login form after update to latest version 116.0.7
[Whm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj0Uq.jpg)

[Cpanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzkFV.jpg)

I've tried to force install cpanel from ssh but the problem still ..

And i've tried to install the latest cpanel to another my server and the problem on another my server